# Conditional variance given condition on both random variables

Tags: probability

[image]

**Correct answer: 2.933**

My work:

Let $X =$ # of hurricanes hitting Florida, $\sim exp(\lambda = 1.7)$,

Y = # of hurricanes hitting Texas, $\sim exp(\lambda = 2.3)$.

$$Var(X-Y|X+Y=3) = E[(X-Y)^2|X+Y=3] - E[X-Y|X+Y=3]^2 $$

$$=E[X^2|X+=3] - 2E[X|X+Y=3]E[Y|X+Y=3] - E[X-Y|X+Y=3]^2$$ by independence. Since $X$, $Y$ are independent, the joint pmf is simply the product of their marginal pmfs, and I tried to fill out a joint pmf table with $X$, $Y$ ranging from $0$ to $3$, since $X+Y=3$. Surely there must be a better way than filling out this table? It would take up way too much time on the exam.

(Exam P Finan 51.22)

Comment: I don't think this problem has a nice closed form. Mathematica was giving expression in terms of Bessel functions and hypergeometric functions when I tried to compute the distribution of $X-Y$ conditioned on $X+Y=n$.

Comment: Please use proper formatting in your posts. Try to type out the question instead of pasting pictures.

Comment: sorry, I will try to do that from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $X+Y=3$, we have $X-Y=2X-(X+Y)=2X-3$, and $\operatorname{Var}(2X-3)=4\operatorname{Var}X$. Given $X+Y=3$, $X$ is a binomial variable with $n=3$ and $p=\frac{1.7}{1.7+2.3}$. You can calculate its variance with the standard formula $np(1-p)$.

Comment: that gives .733, which is not the answer?

Comment: @MinYoungKim: Wow, this shows you how crazy math.SE can be. You asked for a solution that doesn't take up too much time in an exam. I write a three-liner, it gets downvoted. Someone writes a whole page full of tables (which you said you want to avoid), and it gets upvoted. And you point out a non-existent error in my answer. That's a pretty sad state of affairs, altogether :-) What you calculated as approximately $.733$ is $\operatorname{Var}X$. The answer is, as I wrote, $4 \operatorname{Var}X$. Please read more carefully next time.

Comment: oh im sorry, i didn't downvote because the other answer was longer, i downvote bc i thought it was the wrong answer

Comment: @MinYoungKim: OK, I've edited the question so you can change your downvote if you like.

Comment: +1 for the slick solution, but just wanted to point out (to the question-asker) that the complexity of this solution is hidden in the claim "given $X+Y=n$, $X$ is $\text{Binom}(n,\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2))$" which, although true, would need justification if you haven't encountered it in your class/textbook

Comment: yes I have't encountered. what would you suggest would a "normal" solution be? as in no "tricks", the kind I can think of in an exam setting

Comment: @MinYoungKim: It's not actually terribly much effort to do this directly. For the conditional probability, you can disregard the constant factors $\mathrm e^{-\mu_i}$, so you only need to calculate and then normalize four values: $\frac{\mu_1^k\mu_2^{3-k}}{k!(3-k)!}$ for $k=0,\ldots,3$; the corresponding values of $X-Y$ are $-3,-1,1,3$, respectively. But ideally the fact that two Poisson processes are binomially distributed  conditional on their sum should become second nature to you and not seem like a "trick" at all :-) It's quite a useful thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

first we try to find when $X+Y=3$

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
(x,y) & (0,3) & (1,2) & (2,1) & (3,0) \\ \hline
p(x,y) & P_X(0) \times P_Y(3) & P_X(1) \times P_Y(2) & P_X(2) \times P_Y(1)
& P_X(3) \times P_Y(0) \\
\end{array}

```
using this r code 
R code 
t<-0:3
px<-dpois(t,1.7) # P(X=t) [1] 0.18 0.31 0.26 0.15
py<-dpois(t,2.3) # P(Y=t) [1] 0.10 0.23 0.27 0.20
px[1:4]*py[4:1]  # approximately [1] 0.0360 0.0837 0.0598 0.0150
```

\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
(x,y) & (0,3) & (1,2) & (2,1) & (3,0) &sum \\ \hline
p(x,y) & 0.18 \times 0.2=0.036 & 0.31 \times 0.27 =0.0837 & 0.26 \times 0.23=0.0598
& 0.15 \times 0.1=0.015 &0.1945 \\
\end{array}

so 
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
(x,y) & (0,3) & (1,2) & (2,1) & (3,0)  \\ \hline
p(x,y|X+Y=3) & 0.036/0.1945=0.18508997  & 0.0837/0.1945=0.43033419 & 0.0598/0.1945=0.30745501 & 0.015/0.1945=0.07712082   \\
\end{array}

Now you have $P(X,Y|X+Y=3)$ you can calculate what you want.

a simple way is  calculate $P(X-Y=t|X+Y=3)$

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
(x,y) & (0,3) & (1,2) & (2,1) & (3,0) \\ \hline
x-y & (0-3)=-3 & (1-2)=-1 & (2-1)=1 & (3-0)=3 \\ \hline
p(x,y|X+Y=3) & 0.18508997  & 0.43033419 & 0.30745501 
& =0.07712082 \\
\end{array}

```
 useful R code 
  t<-0:3
  px<-round(dpois(t,1.7),2) # P(X=t)
  py<-round(dpois(t,2.3),2) # P(Y=t)
  px[1:4]*py[4:1]
  (px[1:4]*py[4:1])/sum(px[1:4]*py[4:1])
   #[1] 0.18508997 0.43033419 0.30745501 0.07712082
```